# Building my own NativeScript app made of TypeScript and using external Telerik modules

Tags: telerik, typescript, nativescript

I am building a simple NativeScript app, and am trying to do it using a TypeScript base code.

I am using Sublime Text 3 under OSX.

I realized by looking at the demo apps that the `tns_modules` matches the [NativeScript](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript) repository so I added it to my `app/` folder as a Git submodule, and then compiled it (`npm i && grunt`). Is that the wrong way to integrate these modules?

I then realized that I could not just run a `tns emulate android` of my app made of `.ts` files: I had to compile them too. So I set up a Grunt task to do so, but it was not easy to handle the dependencies. I ended up with this `Gruntfile.coffee` in `app/`:

```coffee
module.exports = (grunt) ->
    grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-typescript'

    grunt.config 'typescript',
        build:
            src: [
                '**/*.ts'
                '!*_modules/**'
            ]
            options:
                references: [
                    'tns_modules/bin/dist/definitions/**/*.d.ts'
                ]
                target: 'es5'
                sourceMap: false
                declaration: false
                module: 'commonjs'
                noResolve: true
```

And it works with simple code, e.g. I'm able to extend a module like `Observable` by writing:

```typescript
import observable = require("data/observable");
class Activities extends observable.Observable {
    //...
}
```

I then compile with `grunt` (the `.js` files are created along with the `.ts` ones) and run with `tns emulate android` (with Genymotion emulator).

Is it the right architecture for my development? When I use Telerik Platform, the compilation process is hidden so I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

And now I'm trying to use Telerik's [side-bar](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/apps/TelerikNEXT/TelerikUI/side-bar) module directly in a page's XML file, the way [they do it](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/apps/TelerikNEXT/main-page.xml):

```xml
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" xmlns:tsb="./tns_modules/bin/dist/apps/TelerikNEXT/TelerikUI/side-bar">
    <tsb:SideBar title="MyApp">
        ...
```

But I get this error:

> E/TNS.Native( 2456): TypeError: Cannot read property 'android' of undefined
>   E/TNS.Native( 2456): File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.scmobile/files/app/./tns_modules/bin/dist/apps/TelerikNEXT/TelerikUI/side-bar, line: 39, column: 39

Which corresponds to:

```js
this._android = new com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.RadSideDrawer(this._context);
```

Any idea how I should include these modules? Note that I'm new to mobile dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sidebar, which they're using in the example, is a (payed) [controller from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/ios-ui/sidedrawer).

As such, it needs to be downloaded and added with `tns library add {ios|android} /path/to/the/sidebar`.

> This command will read project.properties file from the specified shared library folder and will add a reference to it in your project. If in turn the shared library has references to other projects then these projects will be included recursively. As a result, this will create a new folder lib which is sibling to already existing app and platforms.
>
> - http://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/external-libs/resource-libs

Comment: I see, but these controls are not free ($500!) and not present in the trial... so I guess I have to make my own?!

Comment: Unfortunately, pretty much so. Or find another component.

Comment: @antoine129 take a look at the animated side menu module that I created. It's not updated for the latest version of NativeScript yet, but it could give you a head start on building your own. [http://nuvious.com/Blog/2015/5/30/its-finally-here-nativescript-animated-side-menu](http://nuvious.com/Blog/2015/5/30/its-finally-here-nativescript-animated-side-menu)